# iOS8 pod 'FMDB/standalone/FTS' DB Error: 1 "unknown tokenizer: unicode61"

Tags: ios, sqlite, full-text-search, cocoapods

I use pod to manage fmdb like this "pod 'FMDB/standalone/FTS', '~> 2.6.2'".
When i add "use_frameworks!" to my Podfile. My app use fmdb search in a FTS database table. It log this error "DB Error: 1 "unknown tokenizer: unicode61"".(The db file in my app used fts unicode61 tokenizer.)
This error only happened on ios8. I build the same code on ios9 and ios10 is work well.

PS：I add "use_frameworks!" to my Podfile is because I want to use some swift Pod lib to my project.

Comment: why not use this instead?  pod 'FMDB'

Comment: pod 'FMDB' will only install FMDB lib. pod 'FMDB/standalone' install FMDB and the  sqlite3 for last version.